# Использование иконок

Tags: android, java

Могу ли я в приложении работать с иконками, находящимися в произвольной директории или я могу использовать иконки только то, что положил `resources/drawable`?

Comment: после просмтра нн-го вопроса для андроида возникла мысль а стоит ли ставить метку java для всех вопросов об андроиде если 99% из них конкретно к java никакого отношения не имеют

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно еще юзать то что в папке assert и на SD-карте.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать файлы, лежащие в любой директории проекта Eclipse(assets, res/raw, res/drawable) или вообще файл находящийся где угодно на девайсе(на карте, или в файлах самого приложения. Только смысл? Иконки обычно ложат в drawable с нужным квалификатором по размеру и жизнь удалась:)